# 4G hostless modem Quanta 1k6e and rndis_host problem

Tags: openwrt, modem, lte

I'm trying to connect 4G modem Quanta 1k6e to my wl500g router with OpenWRT BARRIER BREAKER (14.07-rc2, r41815), but I have a trouble.
When I attach device, in the log appears:

```
Thu Aug 14 21:58:06 2014 kern.info kernel: [  161.580000] usb 2-2: new full-speed USB device number 5 using uhci_hcd
Thu Aug 14 21:58:07 2014 kern.info kernel: [  161.800000] rndis_host 2-2:1.0 eth1: register 'rndis_host' at usb-0000:00:03.0-2, RNDIS device, 00:16:36:9c:4f:b5
```

`00:16:36:9c:4f:b5` - I get this MAC on Windows machine, where my modem works fine.

Next in log:

```
Thu Aug 14 21:58:07 2014 daemon.notice netifd: Interface 'cdc' is enabled
Thu Aug 14 21:58:07 2014 kern.info kernel: [  161.850000] usb-storage 2-2:1.2: USB Mass Storage device detected
Thu Aug 14 21:58:07 2014 kern.info kernel: [  161.850000] scsi5 : usb-storage 2-2:1.2
Thu Aug 14 21:58:07 2014 daemon.notice netifd: Network device 'eth1' link is up
Thu Aug 14 21:58:07 2014 daemon.notice netifd: Interface 'cdc' has link connectivity
Thu Aug 14 21:58:07 2014 daemon.notice netifd: Interface 'cdc' is setting up now
Thu Aug 14 21:58:07 2014 kern.info kernel: [  162.040000] usb 2-2: USB disconnect, device number 5
Thu Aug 14 21:58:07 2014 kern.info kernel: [  162.040000] rndis_host 2-2:1.0 eth1: unregister 'rndis_host' usb-0000:00:03.0-2, RNDIS device
Thu Aug 14 21:58:07 2014 daemon.notice netifd: Network device 'eth1' link is down
Thu Aug 14 21:58:07 2014 daemon.notice netifd: Interface 'cdc' has link connectivity loss
Thu Aug 14 21:58:07 2014 kern.info kernel: [  162.390000] usb 2-2: new full-speed USB device number 6 using uhci_hcd
Thu Aug 14 21:58:07 2014 daemon.notice netifd: Interface 'cdc' is now down
Thu Aug 14 21:58:07 2014 kern.info kernel: [  162.620000] cdc_ether 2-2:1.0 eth1: register 'cdc_ether' at usb-0000:00:03.0-2, CDC Ethernet Device, 00:16:36:51:54:57
Thu Aug 14 21:58:07 2014 daemon.notice netifd: Interface 'cdc' is disabled
Thu Aug 14 21:58:07 2014 kern.info kernel: [  162.650000] usb-storage 2-2:1.2: USB Mass Storage device detected
Thu Aug 14 21:58:07 2014 daemon.notice netifd: Interface 'cdc' is enabled
Thu Aug 14 21:58:07 2014 daemon.notice netifd: Network device 'eth1' link is up
Thu Aug 14 21:58:07 2014 kern.info kernel: [  162.660000] scsi6 : usb-storage 2-2:1.2
Thu Aug 14 21:58:07 2014 daemon.notice netifd: Interface 'cdc' has link connectivity
Thu Aug 14 21:58:07 2014 daemon.notice netifd: Interface 'cdc' is setting up now
Thu Aug 14 21:58:07 2014 daemon.notice netifd: Network device 'eth1' link is down
Thu Aug 14 21:58:07 2014 daemon.notice netifd: Interface 'cdc' has link connectivity loss
Thu Aug 14 21:58:08 2014 daemon.notice netifd: cdc (1614): udhcpc (v1.22.1) started
Thu Aug 14 21:58:08 2014 kern.notice kernel: [  163.730000] scsi 6:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Virtual  Mass-Storage     0000 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
Thu Aug 14 21:58:09 2014 kern.notice kernel: [  163.800000] sd 6:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
Thu Aug 14 21:58:09 2014 kern.notice kernel: [  163.850000] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
Thu Aug 14 21:58:09 2014 daemon.notice netifd: cdc (1614): Sending discover...
Thu Aug 14 21:58:12 2014 daemon.notice netifd: cdc (1614): Sending discover...
Thu Aug 14 21:58:15 2014 daemon.notice netifd: cdc (1614): Sending discover...
```

After that I get `cdc` interface, but without assigned IP address. Even if I assign IP manually:

- 192.168.225.38 (which one is assigned at Windows machine), or
- 192.168.225.1 (which is assigned at WEB UI of the modem as modem's address),

there's no reply.

I tried

```
echo -n 2-2:1.0 > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/cdc_ether/unbind
```

to successfully unbind `cdc_ether`:

```
T:  Bus=02 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=01 Cnt=02 Dev#=  6 Spd=12   MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=02(comm.) Sub=06 Prot=00 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=0408 ProdID=ea45 Rev= 0.00
S:  Manufacturer=QUANTA
S:  Product=Mobile Broadband
S:  SerialNumber=357264046968757
C:* #Ifs= 3 Cfg#= 1 Atr=80 MxPwr=500mA
I:* If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=02(comm.) Sub=06 Prot=00 Driver=(none)
E:  Ad=83(I) Atr=03(Int.) MxPS=  16 Ivl=32ms
I:* If#= 1 Alt= 0 #EPs= 0 Cls=0a(data ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=(none)
I:  If#= 1 Alt= 1 #EPs= 2 Cls=0a(data ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=(none)
E:  Ad=81(I) Atr=02(Bulk) MxPS=  64 Ivl=0ms
E:  Ad=01(O) Atr=02(Bulk) MxPS=  64 Ivl=0ms
I:* If#= 2 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=08(stor.) Sub=06 Prot=50 Driver=usb-storage
E:  Ad=82(I) Atr=02(Bulk) MxPS=   8 Ivl=0ms
E:  Ad=02(O) Atr=02(Bulk) MxPS=  64 Ivl=0ms
```

But when I try to bind `rndis_host driver`:

```
echo -n 2-2:1.0 > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/rndis_host/bind
```

I get an error:

```
write error: No such device
```

Help me please to solve my problem.